# Plotting multiple different histograms based on vector of column names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe that I want to plot a histogram for each column:

```
structure(list(ACTB = c(11.7087918, 13.1847403, 8.767737, 12.2949669, 
12.399929, 12.130683, 9.816222, 10.700336, 11.862543, 12.479818, 
12.48152, 11.798277, 12.0932696, 11.014992, 12.3496682, 11.9810211, 
11.946094, 12.1517049, 11.6794028, 12.4895911, 12.787039, 12.2927522, 
12.746232, 12.4428358, 11.6382198, 11.6833202, 12.3320067, 12.390378, 
12.5550587, 11.597384, 11.7608624, 12.018702, 11.9211984, 11.7143178, 
11.800693, 12.7543979, 12.7028472, 11.6509804, 11.5112258, 12.36468, 
12.0704304, 12.5876125, 12.2929857, 11.764464, 12.3740263, 12.275172, 
11.5247418, 11.9290723, 11.100383, 12.5631062, 10.647334, 12.265323, 
11.457643, 12.194339, 11.468173, 12.355388, 12.3233796, 12.200504, 
11.716417, 12.430028, 11.3201558, 11.43911, 12.9782049, 11.139062, 
11.181185, 10.123614, 11.963833, 10.919224, 11.873896, 11.800616, 
12.2159602, 11.6360763, 11.6204291, 11.5500821, 12.6783682, 11.918854, 
11.8701782, 10.98058, 11.6254916, 12.1558646, 11.533709, 12.0096358, 
12.2830638, 11.772724, 11.8853726, 12.041823, 12.623814, 12.3134903, 
11.6714245, 12.1333082, 12.4747336, 11.5326378, 12.6222532, 10.922728, 
10.9492515, 11.3410073, 12.3005053), ATP5F1 = c(8.3731175, 8.3995189, 
8.871088, 8.4389342, 8.529104, 9.004405, 8.883721, 8.70097, 8.24411, 
8.393635, 8.76813, 8.756177, 8.4418168, 7.986864, 8.4840108, 
8.6523954, 8.5645576, 8.2452877, 8.2440872, 8.7155973, 9.028364, 
8.3578703, 9.007441, 7.8892308, 9.0255621, 8.3165712, 8.3400111, 
8.061171, 8.5216917, 8.337517, 8.2341439, 8.810458, 8.8794988, 
8.4657149, 8.311901, 8.131606, 8.5865282, 9.0900416, 8.8407707, 
7.437107, 8.3982759, 8.7610335, 8.3624475, 8.353429, 8.3630127, 
8.555639, 8.6435841, 8.9587154, 8.517079, 8.9597121, 8.111514, 
8.99767, 8.266991, 8.106218, 8.518875, 8.445485, 8.6409752, 8.662025, 
8.697312, 8.071819, 8.3113401, 8.709276, 8.9154896, 8.138148, 
6.866765, 9.391611, 8.448086, 8.29189, 8.541953, 8.801044, 8.3088083, 
8.288688, 8.8357729, 8.4731257, 8.7321095, 8.383259, 8.4729561, 
5.551528, 8.526436, 8.4548827, 8.242625, 8.9862422, 8.5688994, 
8.848029, 8.2656363, 8.434976, 8.8023704, 8.6692361, 8.4333198, 
8.2926568, 8.2141276, 8.3246346, 7.7262395, 8.0797336, 8.7005427, 
8.7695946, 8.1262312), DDX5 = c(11.3122241, 11.7042284, 8.866042, 
12.0376754, 12.417701, 11.479431, 10.078783, 9.043405, 11.216074, 
11.846906, 11.161803, 8.713301, 11.0790887, 11.685125, 11.9599302, 
12.4036502, 11.9778411, 11.9900709, 11.6069971, 11.2651929, 11.455536, 
12.3741866, 11.558182, 11.498146, 12.5073231, 11.4546523, 11.8465482, 
11.51445, 11.721283, 12.340818, 11.5388553, 11.920725, 11.7067172, 
11.6207138, 11.638226, 11.1407525, 11.5832407, 11.981909, 11.7684202, 
12.435987, 11.5253382, 10.9882446, 12.1789747, 11.956257, 12.5427815, 
12.007658, 11.6360041, 12.2520109, 11.858959, 12.4740761, 6.927855, 
11.117424, 7.749824, 11.518817, 11.322855, 11.74096, 11.768474, 
11.497009, 11.912888, 11.570506, 11.8167398, 11.912566, 11.2631437, 
11.328946, 11.072161, 12.807216, 12.127281, 12.125497, 11.524622, 
11.20101, 11.5451414, 12.0747211, 11.5716524, 11.7223929, 11.8529683, 
11.868865, 11.8998228, 9.859857, 12.1404707, 11.9166386, 12.613162, 
12.9062351, 11.6691732, 11.984726, 11.727059, 11.421816, 11.9506736, 
12.2447547, 11.8167228, 11.9021356, 12.5527606, 12.6511506, 11.8550833, 
11.382018, 11.8314198, 11.8394352, 11.8128198), EEF1G = c(12.622405, 
11.2945857, 8.610078, 13.1323891, 12.702769, 12.319703, 10.181874, 
8.615338, 11.526551, 12.106198, 11.602801, 9.137166, 13.0991666, 
13.049641, 12.2938678, 11.7442632, 12.7866184, 12.6753617, 12.9552413, 
12.0861518, 13.136434, 12.64865, 13.298616, 11.8531038, 12.7791485, 
13.4150478, 11.636058, 12.013313, 11.8785493, 12.771945, 12.5351321, 
13.147321, 11.6760014, 12.2604174, 11.802344, 12.23351, 12.1175728, 
12.7360727, 12.5730595, 11.13, 11.7737462, 11.9774565, 11.8927844, 
12.17392, 12.441605, 12.221691, 12.4866463, 12.5645763, 12.070268, 
12.1801377, 8.80704, 12.288168, 8.298831, 12.234659, 11.832415, 
12.474423, 12.4440819, 11.888544, 11.625162, 12.161204, 12.2707656, 
12.941017, 12.3491325, 12.978561, 11.833124, 11.782119, 12.273029, 
12.462202, 12.538127, 12.236135, 12.2884941, 12.4195123, 12.5274317, 
12.3917089, 11.912339, 12.439751, 12.0962051, 10.912737, 11.999598, 
12.3776528, 11.348448, 12.4151316, 11.5389366, 11.328957, 12.4397802, 
12.238454, 12.0192408, 12.2290439, 12.8381542, 11.1834666, 12.0636739, 
12.4752125, 12.7681644, 12.1747129, 12.7343662, 12.3493937, 11.7971488
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
73L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 102L, 
103L))
```

I want to create a grid of histograms for each column, the list of column is:

```
HK_GENES = c(
  "ACTB", "ATP5F1", "DDX5", "EEF1G"
)
```

Is there a way of doing it with ggplot2?

I tried with no success the following:

```
ggplot(data=df_hk_genes, aes_string(x=HK_GENES)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins=15) + 
  facet_wrap(HK_GENES, nrow = 5, scale = "free_x")
```

In python I could create a subfigure for each histogram an iterate over it.

I have around 20 column in my original dataframe, and I want to avoid calling the same block with different column

Comment: Yes, there is, but in my opinion, you'd be better off making your data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  This will result in more compact code that is more robust and easier to maintain.  Your data frame isn't tidy because your column names contain information: the names of the genes.  A tidy dataset would have columns for,  say, `Gene` and `Value`. [This is essentially what @Mael has done in their answer below.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape the data and facet over the groups.

```r
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

melt(df_hk_genes) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, nrow = 5, scale = "free_x") +
  geom_histogram(bins=15)
```